# Only Select One Radio Button

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I wrote the code below and it works great and does its purpose but i have 2 problems. 1. It allows more than 1 answer to be selected & 2. theres no error message when no answer is selected.

```
<div id="p1" class="SlidingPanelsContent">
  <div class="question"> 
       <div class="label"><span class="number"><?=$question_id++; ?>.</span>
     <? echo $question; ?>
    </div>

<div class="answer" onmouseover="javascript:changeBgColor(event, '#B900A5');" onmouseout="javascript:restoreBgColor(event);"  onclick="this.checked=true; "> 
<input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="<?php echo rand(); ?>" value="<?=$ans1; ?>" ><? echo $ans1; ?></div>

    <div class="answer" onmouseover="javascript:changeBgColor(event, '#B900A5');" onmouseout="javascript:restoreBgColor(event);" onclick="this.checked=true;">
   <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="<?php echo rand(); ?>" value="<?=$ans2; ?>" ><?=$ans2; ?></div>

   <div class="answer" onmouseover="javascript:changeBgColor(event, '#B900A5');" onmouseout="javascript:restoreBgColor(event);" onclick="this.checked=true;">
   <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="<?php echo rand(); ?>" value="<?=$ans3; ?>" ><?=$ans3; ?></div>

   <div class="answer" onmouseover="javascript:changeBgColor(event, '#B900A5');" onmouseout="javascript:restoreBgColor(event);" onclick="this.checked=true;">
    <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" name="<?php echo rand(); ?>" value="<?=$ans4; ?>" ><?=$ans4; ?></div>

   </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: You make radio buttons belong to the same group (that is, allowing only one to be selected) by giving them the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give the radio buttons the same name then only one can be checked as this is enforced by the browser. If you give them different names, like you are by using `rand()` to give them their names, then they all can be checked since they won't be associated with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give same name to radio button, they form a group and you will be able to select only one in a group.

Answer (score 0):

> It allows more than 1 answer to be selected

Stop using random `name` attributes. All `radio` buttons with the same `name` are considered part of the same group, and the browser will only permit one to be selected.

> theres no error message when no answer is selected

You have to implement the logic to do that.